# Design issue on Stack Overflow company team page

Tags: bug, design

I recently visited the [Stack Overflow company team page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team), and observed an anomaly! If you scroll down to the bottom of the page, you will see it on the left bottom of the page. The navigation div on the left begins to float over the footer div when one scrolls past the last row of team members. This animated GIF might help see it clearly.

[image: animation]

The correct behaviour I think is the navigation `div` also moves up along with the last row of team members as it scrolls past that row.

Comment: Nice screen capture skills! :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks Mr. Wizard! Oh no, a duplicate? I thought I was the first to see that. :( The question mine is marked duplicate of is just one month old. I am pretty sure I saw the problem then, but just didn't post it.